# Is there a way to access the collection of current sessions in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, session

Is there any way to access the collection of current sessions in ASP.NET globally from the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, sessions are sandboxed, they are totally separate from each other. What you could do is managing a psueudo-session collection in the shared Application object and implement the Session_Start method to populate that collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you store session state in SQL Server, you would have access to all the sessions via SQL Server.

There is also Application State - which can be used to access information across the application, but this has many caveats.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but you can manage your own list in the global.a s a x

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //add current session to your own application shared collection
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //remove session
}
```

Comment: Can you inspect the contents of the session though?

Comment: Session end event wouldn't occur if session is out of process, even in process, it isn't guaranteed that it's trigged: see note on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end.aspx